# Jenkins sudo - How can I change XCode toolchain in Jenkins job

Tags: xcode, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, sudo

I want to be able to toggle between 2 toolchains when running a Jenkins job.

Normally I would use

```
sudo xcode-select -p /path/to/xcode
```

But I don't think it is suggested to use "sudo" in a Jenkins job.

What is the suggested way to use sudo for this?

Comment: Have you turn out find the answer? I would like to know it too.. thanks...